# Find the matrix for $T$ with respect to the standard bases $B = \{1,x,x^2\}$ for $P_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\ P_2 \to P_2$ be a linear operator defined by

$$T(a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2) = a_0 + a_1 (x-1) + a_2 (x-1)^2.$$

Find the matrix $T$ with respect to the standard basis $B = \{1, x, x^2\}$ for $P_2$.

I know that the solution to this problem is the following matrix, but I don't understand how to find it. I tried to let the $a$ variables be $a$, $b$ and $c$ within my equation. Then, I plugged in the basis but that didn't work.

Answer:
$$T = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 &  -2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: You obviously know LaTeX. Why not using it properly?

Comment: I joined this site 24 hours ago and I am trying to learn to use LaTeX. Terribly sorry if you were unable to read the question.

Comment: Cee: we do really appreciate your effort to format. Your question was very readable, it's just that it is much easier, for you!, knowing that you can write much of what you wrote, and format, with many fewer dollar signs. Click the link immediately above the icon of the last editor: click on "edited x min/hours/days ago" and you can "peek" at updated formatting for the post.

Comment: amWhy, thank you for your help!

Comment: To elaborate my comment: you know subscripts, exponents,... even the bmatrix environment. So, I honestly wondered why not just using this stuff altogether (which would be a bit easier for us to read, and far more easier for you to write). I apologize if I sounded harsh. That was not my intention.

Comment: No problem. I've never used LaTex before so wasn't sure how to write it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 1 &  -2\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} a_0 - a_1 + a_2 \\ a_1 - 2a_2 \\ a_2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

At the same time,
\begin{align}
a_0 + a_1(x-1) + a_2(x-1)^2 &= a_0 + a_1x - a_1 + a_2x^2 - 2a_2x + a_2 \\
&= (a_0 - a_1 + a_2) + (a_1 - 2a_2)x + a_2x^2.
\end{align}
I hope it is more clear this way.

Comment: @amWhy Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Vedran: Thank *you*! +1

Comment: Could you explain how you got the very last step? I'm getting the same answer when I expand, but I'm not sure how you decide which variables go in which group on the last step. I see that there's never more than one of the same variable..

Comment: @Cee I've just grouped all the summands with no $x$ next to them (in the first braces), then I've grouped all with $x$ in the second, while extracting $x$ (i.e., $a_1x - 2a_2x = (a_1 - 2a_2)x$), and so on.

Comment: Okay, I see now. Thanks!

Comment: @Cee You're welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A way to come up with this matrix is to calculate the value of T at each of the basis vectors:

$T(1)=1=1(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)$,  so the first column has entries 1, 0, 0.
$T(x)=x-1=-1(1)+1(x)+0(x^2)$,  so the second column has entries -1, 1, 0.
$T(x^2)=(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1=1(1)+(-2)(x)+1(x^2)$,  so the third column has entries 1, -2, 1.